# Does the sequence $f_n(x)={1+x^n\over 2+x^n}$ converge uniformly on $[0,1)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Does the sequence of functions $$f_n(x)={1+x^n\over 2+x^n}$$ 
converge uniformly to ${1\over 2}$ on the interval $0\le x\lt1$?

I don't think so because  $\sup\left|f_n(x)-{1\over2}\right|=1$. If the interval is $[0,a]$ where $0\lt a\lt1$, then I think this is true.

Comment: Note that $\lim_{x \uparrow 1} f_n(x) = {2 \over 3}$ for all $n$. The $\sup$ above should be ${1 \over 6}$. Show that $f_n$ is increasing and always $\ge {1 \over 2}$. This lets you compute the $\sup$ in the $[0,a]$ case.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks. I got it. Since $f_n(x)$ is increasing function on [0,1), the supremum should be ${1 \over 6}$ hence it is not uniformly converging to ${1 \over 2}$.

Comment: Correct. Since it is increasing and bounded below by a half, you can directly show that it  converges uniformly on $[0,a]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, it is not uniformly convergent. And given $\varepsilon>0$, you can even find how badly $N(x)$ degenerates as $x$ approaches 1, where $N(x)\in\mathbb{N}$ is such that $|f_n(x)-0.5|<\varepsilon,\forall n>N(x)$. Notice that

$$
f_n(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{2+x^n}
$$

so

$$
\left|f_n(x)-\frac{1}{2}\right| = \frac{x^n}{4+2x^n}<\varepsilon
$$

If you solve for $x$ you obtain $x^n<\frac{4\varepsilon}{1-2\varepsilon}$, which gives (recall that $x<1$, so $\log_x(b)$ is decreasing)

$$
n>\log_x\frac{4\varepsilon}{1-2\varepsilon}=\frac{\ln\frac{4\varepsilon}{1-2\varepsilon}}{\ln x}
$$

So $N(x)$ blows up roughly as $1/(x-1)$ as $x$ approaches 1.

Edit: yes, if you restrict your attention to $[0,a]$ with $0<a<1$, then $N(x)$ as a maximum, so the sequence uniformly converges.